# setInterval not working properly on safari web extension

Tags: safari, safari-extension, browser-extension, safari-web-inspector, safari-web-extension

I've recently ported my chrome extension to safari using the safari web extension converter: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions/converting_a_web_extension_for_safari.

However, I'm finding that my setInterval calls only executed a set number of times in the background page. When I open the background page for my web extension, I've tried running a simple interval to see the result:

[Safari Web Extension Background Page with interval stuck after running set number of times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHWxW.png)

When I try the same thing for my chrome web extension, the interval runs indefinitely:

[Chrome Web Extension Background Page with interval running continuously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKejV.png)

If I try to run the interval after opening the dev console for any random web page in Safari, the interval works fine:

[Safari content page with interval running continuously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAV80.png)

Similarly, a recursive setTimeout function fails in the background page for the web extension:

[Recursive setTimeout function in my background page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw4uY.png)
[Result of recursive set timeout function in my background page (stops afterwards)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoCY6.png)

I'm not sure why timers might be failing in background page for Safari. My extension works perfectly fine in chrome/brave/firefox. Thanks!

Comment: I have a same issue. Have you ever figured out how to solve it?

Comment: No, I did not figure this out

Answer (score 1):

When the extension is not active safari browser stops the background process of that specific extension.

Alternative approach: You can create a timeout in the content script and message background from the content script periodically to check your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same issue. `setInterval()` was throttled after 6 iterations, no matter the interval. Calls were made, but sporadically, like once a minute at first and even further apart later.

I fixed this by switching to [alarms API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/alarms) instead of `setInterval()`. Seems to work fine.

Safari 16.3, macOS 12.6 Monterey.